# PERL MCE::Grep - Why doesn't mce grep pattern work when dynamically passed in a loop

Tags: perl, perl-mce

I am using MCE::Grep module to grep the contents of files.

```
use MCE::Grep;
my $patt="Jack";
my @arr1 = mce_grep_f { /$patt/ } 'logFile';
chomp(@arr1);
for my $line1 (@arr1){
    print "$line1\n";
}
```

It works fine when executed as a single command as above.

```
my @arr=undef;
for $i (@list) {
    print "List : $i\n";
    @arr = mce_grep_f { /$i/ } 'logFile';
    chomp(@arr);
    for my $line (@arr){
            print "$line\n";
    }
}
```

But there is an issue while executing the same in a for loop. I guess it might be some syntax issue. Please share suggestions.

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: @Biffen `@list` is array which contains the patterns to be used in the grep command.  Issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MCE::Grep;

my @list = ('Jack', 'Hobbie');

my $pat = join('|', @list);
my @arr = mce_grep_f { /$pat/ } 'logFile';

chomp(@arr);

for my $line (@arr){
   print "$line\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..     Actually my code works.. Silly mistake as mentioned in question.  Didnt decalre $i inside for loop.  It should have been "for my $i .."